# Should "to" be used after "appeared" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, relative-clauses

> In 2006 he organised the wedding of the daughter of the then leader of Myanmar's junta, in which guests **appeared draped** in diamonds and **drunk** on cascades of champagne.

This sentence is from an [article](https://www.economist.com/news/obituary/21582234-lo-hsing-han-heroin-king-and-business-tycoon-died-july-6th-aged-about-80-lo-hsing-han), I'm little confused about the bold part, it seems that it should be "...guests appeared to drape...and drink.."

Answer (score 1):

The original sentence is correct.  The guests **appeared** - that is, they *arrived*.  In what way did they appear?  **Draped** in diamonds, and **drunk**.  Those are just adjectives describing the way in which the guests were performing the action of "appearing".

To say that the guests "appeared to drape in diamonds" would mean that the guests *seemed* to be draping *something else* in diamonds.  To say that the guests "appeared to drink" would mean that it looked like they were drinking.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any difference if the sentence paragraphed like: "in which guests **appeared draping** in diamonds and **drinking** on cascades of champagne"?

Comment: "appeared draping in diamonds" is wrong because "draping" is a *present participle* and would mean that the guests were covering something else with diamonds.  "appeared...drinking on cascades of champagne" is wrong because we say they were "drinking champagne", not "drinking *on* champagne".  Also, it changes the meaning.  Saying they "appeared *drinking*" means that they were in the act of drinking, whereas *drunk* means that they were intoxicated.

Answer (score 0):

No, that wouldn't be correct. If you wanted to rewrite the sentence using *to*, you could say it like this:

> In 2006 he organised the wedding of the daughter of the then leader of Myanmar's junta, in which guests **appeared** **to be draped in diamonds** and [to be] drunk on cascades of champagne.

As for your wording, that could be used if you were talking about something else:

> In 2006 he organised the wedding of the daughter of the then leader of Myanmar's junta, in which guests **appeared to drape themselves** in diamonds and drink on cascades of champagne.